# Bash scripting Issue when running command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Trying to run what I thought would be a simple command from within a BASH script, but it seems to be catching me out on something. I want to collect `vstat` information of a number of Java processes and append to separate files. So I thought I would try with one, then expand,... It shouldn't be too hard.

Here's the script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo JSTATS from Components
    # Variables
WorkflowLog=">> /tmp/jsm04-workflow-gc.log"
Workflow=$(ps -ef | grep 'java' | grep -i 'workflowcomponent' |   awk '{print "jstat -gcutil "$2" 200 10"}')
echo $Workflow
echo $WorkflowLog
echo Running jstats...............................
command $Workflow $WorkflowLog
```

When the script runs I get the following error:

```
Running jstats...............................
invalid argument count
Usage: jstat -help|-options
```

So am I passing the command incorrectly or should I be running command lines in a slightly different manner? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Just noticed when using -vx the following debug.. How do I pass the '>>' as I think this is the issue.                                                          command jstat -gcutil 30468 200 10 '>>' /tmp/jsm04-workflow-gc.log + jstat -gcutil 30468 200 10 '>>' /tmp/jsm04-workflow-gc.log

Comment: have you tried awk '{print "jstat -gcutil "$2" 200 10"}' on its own (directly in bash, no script?) I think this wont work because your quotes look wrong

Comment: Works fine - on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If it - was a problem with the variable.

```
WorkflowLog=$(>> /tmp/jsm04-workflow-gc.log)
```

Comment: Okay thought I had fixed it, but my command doesn't use the second variable                                                                                        command $variable1 $variable2

Answer (score 0):

You can't store shell constructs like `>>` in a variable, and your variable `Workflow` is the *result* of the command, not the command line itself. Code to execute belongs in a function, not as a text parameter.

You should structure your code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo JSTATS from Components
# Variables
WorkflowLog="/tmp/jsm04-workflow-gc.log"
Workflow () {
    ps -ef | 
     grep 'java' | 
     grep -i 'workflowcomponent' |  
     awk '{print "jstat -gcutil "$2" 200 10"}'
}

echo Running jstats...............................
Workflow >> "$WorkflowLog"
```